# Antlr4 radix number grammar

Tags: numbers, antlr4, grammar

```
grammar Number;

numbers: (radix_number Whitespace)+;


radix_number
    : '2#' Bin
    | '8#' Octals
    | '16#' Hex
    | '10#' Decimals
    ;

Octals: Octal+;
Hex: Hexdecimal+;
Bin: Binary+;
Decimals: Digit+;

Whitespace
    : [ \t\f\r\n]+
    ;

fragment Digit
    : [0-9]
    ;

fragment Binary
    : '0' | '1'
    ;

fragment Hexdecimal
    : [0-9A-Fa-f]
    ;

fragment Octal
    : [0-7]
    ;
```

Hi, I'm using the above grammar to parse radix numbers. The input "8#12777166 16#0912345678abcdef " is working, but "2#1010 10#1241249 " is not working and pops the following errors.

```
line 1:2 mismatched input '1010' expecting Bin
line 1:10 mismatched input '1241249' expecting Decimals
```

It seems to be a little weird. Any suggestion to correct it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANTLR's lexer operates in a very consistent way:

- use the lexer rule that matches the most amount of characters
- when 2 or more rules match the same amount of characters, let the one defined first "win"

Because of that, input like `1010` will always become an `Octals` token. Yes, it matches `Hex`, `Bin` and `Decimals` too, but `Octals` it defined first. It doesn't matter if the parser tries to match a `Bin` token after it "sees" a `2#` token: the lexer operates independently from the parser.

The solution: do no try to match/create tokens in the parser. Keep them in the lexer:

```
radix_number
    : Bin
    | Octals
    | Hex
    | Decimals
    ;

Octals: '8#' Octal+;
Hex: '16#' Hexdecimal+;
Bin: '2#' Binary+;
Decimals: '10#' Digit+;
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It's really helpful. I'm writing the grammar file for Postscript.